# How to type if elsif on a line inside for for in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to get the minimum lines for the code

However I need a condition where i ** 2> num is sending a message with elif, else works but the code gets an error getting the square root

(GoTr)

```py
num = int(input('num: ')); [print(f'Raiz({num}) = {i}') for i in range(1, num) if i ** 2 == num]
```

Comment: don't use list-comp for side effects (printing in this case). Use it if you actually need the result list. Also putting two lines in 1 with `;` is highly un-readable. with that said you need to do `[print(...) if x else print(...) for i in l]`. the construct you're using is for filterring the list

Comment: I used list-comp because it's a way to make the code much smaller instead of using ``; `` which also counts as a line break. if used ``; `` is pretty much the same as writing in normal form.

Comment: *smaller* code is not (always) *better* code... readability should always count

Comment: In the code above there is the exception of the variable num, but it is part of an external line, so as to give a better appearance or single line.

Comment: There is not a good reason for having code on fewer lines.

Comment: @Almo maybe if you're **really** low on memory and have to save those `'\n'`...

Comment: calm down, man, I'm seeing if there's any way to do this, it's not a matter of saving or not, it's more a matter of some way of reducing code, maybe someday it's needed or something.

Comment: I'm calm man, what I mean is that I already have a code with acceptable efficiency with more than one line, now I don't care if it's one or forty lines, I'm just looking for solutions that might be useful one day. At this point trying to create something with fewer executable and efficient lines is a challenge, even though it may sometimes be unreadable, at least you did it, even though the few lines may be unnecessary.

Comment: Cool man whatever rocks your boat. I am just thinking a good way to reduce code is using good coding practices like inheritance and functions to reuse code, not just pack it all to one-line. Again, **that** will be useful for you in the future. In the end you are not paying rent on your code, so your main focus should be on how well it performs the job, and how easy it will be for someone to understand just by going over it. That's my opinion and I hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example put the `if-else` inside the `print` function:

```
num = int(input('num: ')); [print(f'Raiz({num}) = {i}' if i ** 2 > num else 'not') for i in range(1, num)]
```

You can also kinda use `if-elif-else`:

```
num = int(input('num: ')); [print(f'Raiz({num}) = {i}' if i ** 2 == num else 'lower' if i ** 2 < num else 'higher') for i in range(1, num)]
```

But I really don't see a reason to do it like this, unless you're code-golfing.

Comment: hehehe i'm not playing golf hehe, i'm just trying to go deeper, i know that it is not necessary but nothing better than testing your ability to lower your code hehe even sometimes failing.

Comment: @hx7f It's not really clear what your wanted output is.